# Http request in JSP opens a session?

Tags: jsp, session

0
votar contra
favorita

I have a web application that contains some JSP pages that return a JSON.

This application has a very large flow of hits, and noticed that there were many open sessions in the monitoring area of the glassfish server.

Watch a piece of code that is in the JSP:

```
<%
     RequestLive live = new RequestLive();
     out.print(live.search());
%>
```

That's all I have in the JSP, the rest of the Java class does, and JSON print on a page.

The real question is, a session is open if I access the URL for the data?

> ```
> Ex: www.mydomain.com/RequestLive.jsp
> ```

You must call the `session.invalidade ();` ?

Comment: "*0 votar contra favorita*"? Is the question related to JSF somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a session, then don't create one. You can use this page directive.

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```